# Passing json through a controller

Tags: json, asp.net-core-3.0

I have this back-end system that produces json. Is it possible to pass that data through a controller on request and correctly setting the mimetype? Everything I've tried so far tries to re-serialize the data and thus escaping json string.

I've tried adding `[Produces("application/json")]` to the controller. Setting the response type: `Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;`, returning a JsonResult object: `return new JsonResult(jsonString);`

The back-end doesn't have a JsonSerializer I can add to the JsonSerializerOptions and I only need it for this specific controller.

In short: If I just return the json string as an IActionResult without doing anything the controller works except for the fact that the content-type isn't set to application/json. Is there any way to do this without affecting anything else?

I feel like this shouldn't be such a exceptional use case but I just can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Hello! Would you be able to share the code that you had used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same need.  I solved it by having my action method return an `ActionResult` like so:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(){

  string json = GetJsonFromBackenend();

   return new ContentResult {
                Content = json,
                ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK
            };

}
```

You could declare the return type as an `IActionResult` if you prefer as @Jurgy mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! Using the interface `IActionResult` as return type works as well though.